# Using PHP to change HTML elements

Tags: php, html, ajax, dom

I have a simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">Nothing here</p>
    <button onclick="?">Button</button>       
</body>
</html>
```

and a separate PHP file:

```
<?php 

// Load and exec craigslist
$site = curl_init("https://www.craigslist.org/about/sites");
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$target = curl_exec($site);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom -> loadHTML($target);

// Save logo text 
$title = $dom -> getElementById('logo') -> nodeValue;

?>
```

Here's what I want to do:

When I click the button on the HTML page, I want the PHP script to run so that I can get the craigslist title and store it a PHP variable (`$title`). I want to replace the text in `<p id="demo>` ("Nothing here") with the text stored in $title ("craigslist").

How do I do this?

Comment: Uh. What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what you're trying to do, but in general I think you may want to be using Javascript to do it, not PHP

Comment: I was following you until you said "on a button click". PHP runs on the server, it doesn't react to clicks.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language — therefore you cannot use PHP to modify anything on the page based on a button click. You can, however, use AJAX, where you call for the PHP-generated content with JS, and replace `<p id="demo">` with the fetch content.

Comment: save your html file as a php file and add your code to it.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes @DaOgre Here's what I want to do: 

When I click the button on the HTML page, I want the PHP script to run so that I can get the craigslist title and store it a PHP variable ($title). I want to replace the text in `<p id="demo>` (Nothing here) with the text stored in $title ("craigslist").

Comment: @Terry I think that is exactly what I want. Could you please provide a simple working example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">Nothing here</p>
    <button onclick="myFunc()">Button</button>       
    <script>
    function myFunc() {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php",true); //Change file.php to the location of your php file
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And add this line to your PHP file `after` setting the title variable

```
echo $title;
```

Now of course best case scenario you would use jQuery's built-in AJAX but this works well enough